# AWS CloudFormation: SecurityGroup refers to another security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

This code throws a "Group Description Empty" when that part is full.

```
Resources:
  FormulationSG:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: 'Name'
          Value: 'FormulationSG'
      VpcId: 'vpc-yyy00yyy'
      GroupDescription: 'Port Rules for Formulation and on Port 11.'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 192.168.0.0/8
          FromPort: '11'
          ToPort: '11'
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '91'
          ToPort: '91'
          SourceSecurityGroupName: 'sg-1234567'
```

Ignore all the numbers were changed but the problem I am having is once I tried to source an existing security group 'sg-1234567' and it gives me an error message saying group description is invalid when it is already there in quotes.

Comment: Is this a VPC security group or non-VPC? For instances in VPC, you have to specify `SourceSecurityGroupId`. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-sourcesecuritygroupname

Comment: `sg-1234567` is a security group id, not name.

Comment: Note - I had to delete the second "Security Group Ingress" block.

Comment: @Dasman You should probably remove your edit in the op, and show the line you needed to remove. It was a bit confusing seeing you comment about needing to delete the second SGI block, but it not be there. Maybe post the corrected version as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SourceSecurityGroupName` is for EC2 classic only. You are using VPC EC2 (which is recommended). Use `SourceSecurityGroupId` instead. You do not need to use quotes. This example will work fine:

```
Resources:
  FormulationSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: FormulationSG
      VpcId: vpc-yyy00yyy
      GroupDescription: Port Rules for Formulation and on Port 11.
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 192.168.0.0/8
          FromPort: 11
          ToPort: 11
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 91
          ToPort: 91
          SourceSecurityGroupId: sg-1234567
```

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the comma part!

Comment: Also, you can refer other SG as follow:

`SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt OtherSecurityGroup.GroupId`

_Instead of hard-code the Security Groupd ID_

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SourceSecurityGroupName` property but you are not passing a `Name`... You are passing the `ID`. Therefore try to use `SourceSecurityGroupId` instead of `SourceSecurityGroupName` ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This always irritates me when I'm so close.